# HBase error: Not a host:port pair

Tags: hbase

Hi I am using hBase in fully distributed mode and i am trying to connect Hbase using a java code and create a table. I get an error. Its not connecting to hbase. I have checked all the processes they are running fine:- namenode, datanode, nodemanager, resource manager, hbase master, hbase regionservers, zookeeper.

## Error

```
starting...
getting config...
12/07/25 18:48:31 WARN hbase.HBaseConfiguration: instantiating HBaseConfiguration() is deprecated. Please use HBaseConfiguration#create() to construct a plain Configuration
12/07/25 18:48:32 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.3.2-1031432, built on 11/05/2010 05:32 GMT
12/07/25 18:48:32 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:host.name=aniket
12/07/25 18:48:32 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.version=1.7.0_05
12/07/25 18:48:32 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
12/07/25 18:48:32 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.home=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre
12/07/25 18:48:32 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.class.path=/root/workspace/HBaseTesting/bin:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/hadoop-core.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-common.jar:/root/Downloads/google-collect-1.0-rc1/google-collect-1.0-rc1.jar:/root/Downloads/hbase-0.90.5/hbase-0.90.5.jar:/root/Downloads/hbase-0.90.5/lib/activation-1.1.jar:/root/Downloads/hbase-0.90.5/lib/asm-3.1.jar:/root/Downloads/hbase-0.90.5/lib/avro-1.3.3.jar:/root/Downloads/hbase-0.90.5/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/root/Downloads/hbase-0.90.5/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/root/Downloads/hbase-0.90.5/lib/commons-el-1.0.jar:/root/Downloads/hbase-0.90.5/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/root/Downloads/hbase-0.90.5/lib/commons-lang-2.5.jar:/root/Downloads/hbase-0.90.5/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/root/Downloads/hbase-0.90.5/lib/commons-net-1.4.1.jar:/root/Downloads/hbase-0.90.5/lib/core-3.1.1.jar:/root/Downloads/hbase-0.90.5/lib/guava-r06.jar:/root/Downloads/hbase-0.90.5/lib/hadoop-core-0.20-append-r1056497.jar:/root/Downloads/hbase-0.90.5/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.5.5.jar:/root/Downloads/hbase-0.90.5/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.5.5.jar:/root/Downloads/hbase-0.90.5/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.4.2.jar:/root/Downloads/hbase-0.90.5/lib/jackson-xc-1.5.5.jar:/root/Downloads/hbase-0.90.5/lib/jasper-compiler-5.5.23.jar:/root/Downloads/hbase-0.90.5/lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar:/root/Downloads/hbase-0.90.5/lib/jaxb-api-2.1.jar:/root/Downloads/hbase-0.90.5/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.12.jar:/root/Downloads/hbase-0.90.5/lib/jersey-core-1.4.jar:/root/Downloads/hbase-0.90.5/lib/jersey-json-1.4.jar:/root/Downloads/hbase-0.90.5/lib/jersey-server-1.4.jar:/root/Downloads/hbase-0.90.5/lib/jettison-1.1.jar:/root/Downloads/hbase-0.90.5/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/root/Downloads/hbase-0.90.5/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/root/Downloads/hbase-0.90.5/lib/jruby-complete-1.6.0.jar:/root/Downloads/hbase-0.90.5/lib/jsp-2.1-6.1.14.jar:/root/Downloads/hbase-0.90.5/lib/jsp-api-2.1-6.1.14.jar:/root/Downloads/hbase-0.90.5/lib/jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar:/root/Downloads/hbase-0.90.5/lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar:/root/Downloads/hbase-0.90.5/lib/protobuf-java-2.3.0.jar:/root/Downloads/hbase-0.90.5/lib/servlet-api-2.5-6.1.14.jar:/root/Downloads/hbase-0.90.5/lib/slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar:/root/Downloads/hbase-0.90.5/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar:/root/Downloads/hbase-0.90.5/lib/stax-api-1.0.1.jar:/root/Downloads/hbase-0.90.5/lib/thrift-0.2.0.jar:/root/Downloads/hbase-0.90.5/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/root/Downloads/hbase-0.90.5/lib/zookeeper-3.3.2.jar:/root/Downloads/hbql-0.90.0.1/hbql-0.90.0.1.jar
12/07/25 18:48:32 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.library.path=/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
12/07/25 18:48:32 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
12/07/25 18:48:32 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.compiler=<NA>
12/07/25 18:48:32 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.name=Linux
12/07/25 18:48:32 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.arch=amd64
12/07/25 18:48:32 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.version=2.6.18-274.el5xen
12/07/25 18:48:32 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.name=root
12/07/25 18:48:32 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.home=/root
12/07/25 18:48:32 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.dir=/root/workspace/HBaseTesting
12/07/25 18:48:32 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=192.168.1.88:2181 sessionTimeout=180000 watcher=hconnection
12/07/25 18:48:32 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server /192.168.1.88:2181
12/07/25 18:48:32 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to aniket/192.168.1.88:2181, initiating session
12/07/25 18:48:32 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server aniket/192.168.1.88:2181, sessionid = 0x138bf7676070043, negotiated timeout = 40000
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a host:port pair: �
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HServerAddress.<init>(HServerAddress.java:60)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterAddressTracker.getMasterAddress(MasterAddressTracker.java:63)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getMaster(HConnectionManager.java:561)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.<init>(HBaseAdmin.java:99)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.checkHBaseAvailable(HBaseAdmin.java:1320)
    at HBaseCreateTable.main(HBaseCreateTable.java:38)
```

## code snippet

```
Configuration config=HBaseConfiguration.create();
config.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "192.168.1.88");
config.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort","2181");
config.set("hbase.master", "192.168.1.88:60000");
HTableDescriptor ht = new HTableDescriptor( "abc" );
ht.addFamily( new HColumnDescriptor( "number" ) ); // from and to
HBaseAdmin hba = new HBaseAdmin( conf );
hba.createTable( ht );
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've seen "not a host:port pair" when using 0.90.2 client to talk to 0.92 server.  Can you verify that your client and server HBase versions are the same, and what are they?

Comment: Yes, the samething happened when I accidentally used 0.94 to connect to 0.98.

Answer (score 0):

> i faced same problem, try :
>
> Change your build path jar/wars that you are using, make compatible with Hbase server version.. use same version
>   of Hbase server and jars you used for coding. Ex:if you are using
>   Hbase 0.90.2  server use same version of jars available.

Answer (score 0):

[Check this out](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hbase-user/201201.mbox/%3CCADcMMgHNTcEzSxEt=boYt5xr-UMu4t5QyfeaS2LRQuBV4_T2rg@mail.gmail.com%3E)

if you try to communicate between hbase client 0.90.x and hbase server 0.92.x, this kinds of problems will be happened.

if someone know this problem detailedly, please comment it about reasons.

Comment: You should better [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) instead.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what walter has said. Its not just because of this specific version what he has mentioned '0.90.2' in fact you'll get this exception whenever their will be mismatch between version of client APIs & server APIs.

As i've got the same exception :-

**"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a host:port pair: PBUF"**

when i was using Client API of 0.94 and server APIs of 0.98 version.