# Not a host:port while connecting hbase using java

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

```
public class HbaseConnectorClass {

private HTable table; 
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HbaseConnectorClass.class); 

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    System.out.println("trying to connect ......");
    Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();

    conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "localhost");
    conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2222");
    conf.set("hbase.master", "localhost:60000");        

    try
    {
        System.out.println("Hbase is running!");
        HTable table = new HTable(conf,"personal");
        Put put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes("doe-john-m-12345"));
        put.add(Bytes.toBytes("personal"), Bytes.toBytes("givenName"), Bytes.toBytes("John"));
        put.add(Bytes.toBytes("personal"), Bytes.toBytes("mi"), Bytes.toBytes("M"));
        put.add(Bytes.toBytes("personal"), Bytes.toBytes("surame"), Bytes.toBytes("Doe"));
        put.add(Bytes.toBytes("contactinfo"), Bytes.toBytes("email"), Bytes.toBytes("john.m.doe@gmail.com"));
        table.put(put);
        table.flushCommits();
        table.close();

        System.out.println("Table created");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
}
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a
>   host:port pair: PBUF hadoop�}�����*�} at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Addressing.parseHostname(Addressing.java:60)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ServerName.(ServerName.java:96)at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ServerName.parseVersionedServerName(ServerName.java:278)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterAddressTracker.bytesToServerName(MasterAddressTracker.java:77)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterAddressTracker.getMasterAddress(MasterAddressTracker.java:61)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getMaster(HConnectionManager.java:631)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.(HBaseAdmin.java:106)
>   at
>   com.networkfleet.hbase.practice.HbaseConnectorClass.creatTable(HbaseConnectorClass.java:82)at
>   com.networkfleet.hbase.practice.HbaseConnectorClass.main(HbaseConnectorClass.java:63)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11649824/hbase-error-not-a-hostport-pair

Answer (score 1):

Most probably due to version mismatch between HBase server and the HBase client jars

Check your Server and Client versions